# How to change the implicit used classes in react-boostrap's components?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

By default `react-boostrap` add's the classes `card-title` and `h5` to a `<Card.Title> Foo </Card.Title>` tag.

How can I *remove* or *replace* the `h5` element eg. with `h4`?

Answer (score 0):

Class `h5` is added, not the `h5` element...

Instead of replacing, you can style the `h5` class inside the `.card-body > .card-title.h5` to be just like your `h4` element - using the CSS below:

```
<style>
    .card-body > .card-title.h5 { color:red; font-size:large; }
</style>
```